# Idea / Java : how to remove an artifact?

Tags: java, libraries, artifacts

I need to build a project that refers to another (I'm newbie in Java development using idea 14).

The first let's call it *"commons"* contains based classes to use in all my future projects.

The second let's call it *"app1"* contains a JavaFx application.

I created an artifacts in Java from the "commons" idea project and added it as a module in the "app1" project structure.

1. is it the best way to build such a relationship between java projects ?
2. I can't access resource files (.xml files) located in the "commons" jar structure. Some code in the "commons" project uses sql/some.description.xml files. When I use the corresponding calss in the "app1" project , the relative path is built from the calling class in the "app1" project but files are located in the "commons" library jar file .. any idea to fix/change the code to be able to access resource located in the module jar file ?
3. I can't get deleting any artifact defined in the "commons" projet structure. How to cleanup ?

thanks for your answers

Comment: Show your code for the second bullet. You can use different resource "locators" depending on your needs. So show us what you tried.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking is about. but, if you want to remove an artifact, then you can remove it from the project structure dialog (File -> Project Structure) right?